# increase the DateTimePicker.dateValue

Tags: c#, datetime

I am using the DateTimePicker

Now, how do I increase the dateValue by click on the Button

EX:

dtp.DateValue = 1999/8/20

click on Button ----------> dtp.DateValue = dtp.DateValue + x

x is: (number)

thanks

Comment: What are you wanting to increase, the days?

Comment: What's confusing me is the [DateTimePicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value.aspx) has a Value property, but not a DateValue property.  It isn't surprising everyone is giving answers that don't work.  Are you really using a DateTimePicker?

Comment: It's even more confusing because your "DateValue" property appears to be a string, not a DateTime as implied by the name.

Comment: are you there, you have not reply me ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. I've been reading the responses to you question and there are some good responses in there. If I could make a suggestion - please reduce you use of exclamation points in you comment responses. While I know your problem may be frustrating you, people are trying to help you for free. The use of "!!!!" typically indicates yelling. Try to think about what they are trying to tell you and ask questions (calmly) for clarification.

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
dateTimePicker1.Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(1);
```

Comment: thanx. but i haven't Value. i only have DateValue

Comment: try dtp.DateValue = dtp.DateValue.AddDays(x); ?

Comment: then try to use DateValue.AddDayes()

Comment: it your DateValue is string, try 
 dtp.DateValue = DateTime.Parse(dtp.DateValue).AddDays(x).ToString()

Comment: error: Conversion from string "14 12:00:00 PM" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

Comment: @mah_85: relax dude. These people are helping you completely out of good will.

Comment: @mah_85: Everyone is having to guess the data type of your DateValue member.  Calm down and provide some useful information.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to add days  then you need to use AddDays and others methods are 
 AddHours Method
  AddMilliseconds Method
  AddMinutes Method 
 AddMonths Method 
 AddSeconds Method 
 AddTicks Method
  AddYears Method 
 method in value of datetimepicker control

Answer (score 1):

If dtp.DateValue is string of format like "6/15/2009 1:45:30 PM" 
then this should work

```
dtp.DateValue = DateTime.Parse(dtp.DateValue).AddDays(10).ToString()
```

Otherwise you would have to post your date string format.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Can this help you

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
            dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1.DateValue);
            dt=dt.AddDays(1);
            dateTimePicker1.DateValue= dt.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Comment: dt = Years, months, days, hours, minutes, seconds # But: dateTimePicker1.DateValue = Years, months, days

Comment: error: Conversion from string "14 12:00:00 PM" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

Comment: dt = Years, months, days, hours, minutes, seconds # But: dateTimePicker1.DateValue = Years, months, days

Comment: dateTimePicker1.DateValue haven,t time

Comment: dateTimePicker1.DateValue value is string

Comment: i haven't Dayes.add() and months.add() and ... Add()

Comment: @Student: You can't cast a string directly to a DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

DateTimePicker1.Value = DateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(1)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done. Increase the date by pressing the button.

```
    private void btn_increment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime dt = new DateTime();
        dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Value);
        dt = dt.AddDays(0);
        dateTimePicker1.Value = dt.AddDays(1);       
    }
```